# MySQL Order by date with GROUP BY DATE FORMAT is alphabetical

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is my query:

```
Select Date_format(`date`, '%b %Y') as 'Categories',
..... as 'a1',....... as 'a2'
FROM table1
GROUP BY Date_format(`date`, '%b %Y')
ORDER BY Date_format(`date`, '%b %Y') ASC
```

Answer is alphabetical because, `date_format` convert date to string, I need sorting by date, but, group by is the problem. I need `group by` only for  `Date_format('date','%b %Y')`

Please give a solution

Answer (score 5):

Of course it is alphabetical.  You are ordering by a string.  Try:

```
ORDER BY MIN(date) ASC
```

This will order by the date value.

Note that in the original version of your question, you had single quotes around `date`.  That will not order by anything at all, because `'date'` is a string with a four letter word in it.

Comment: The `MIN(date)` was what ultimately got this to work for me – ordering simply by `date` without using some kind of aggregator like `MIN()` (like some of these other answers suggest) throws an SQL error for me: "Expression ... of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column ... which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause"

Comment: @wosevision . . . You might consider accepting this answer.

Comment: it wasn't my question to accept, but I've already added my upvote to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
Select Date_format(`date`,'%b %Y') as 'Categories',
..... as 'a1',....... as 'a2'
FROM table1
GROUP BY Date_format(`date`,'%b %Y')
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: Use backticks around table and column names, not single quotes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: Aah, yes. You are correct. They got converted during copy/paste from the original question...

Comment: In this case, 'date' should be in 'SELECT' also, or not? Thanks

Comment: No, not necessarily. You can always order on any columns you like without having to include them in the select clause.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this question putting double quotes

```
Select Date_format(`date`, '%b %Y') as 'Categories',
..... as 'a1',....... as 'a2'
FROM table1
GROUP BY Date_format(`date`, '%b %Y')
ORDER BY "categories" ASC
```